# Replace multiple urls with multiple classes

Tags: jquery

Looking to turn these two scripts into one.

```
var removeLocaleLink = $(".int-tooltip a, .int-tooltip");

      removeLocaleLink.each(function(){
        $(this).attr("href", (_, href) =>
      href.replace(/\/zh-hant\/|\/de\/|\/fr\/|\/es\/|\/pt-br\/|\/ja\/|\/ko\//, "/") ); 
    })
```

```
   var removeLocaleLinkOne= $(".int-tooltip");
      removeLocaleLinkOne.each(function(){
        $(this).attr("href", (_, href) =>
      href.replace(/\/zh-hant\/|\/de\/|\/fr\/|\/es\/|\/pt-br\/|\/ja\/|\/ko\//, "/") ); 
    })
```

I tried turning the variable to `var removeLocaleLink = $(".int-tooltip, .int-tooltip a");` but I get an error and it only does the first item on the page.

Comment: Please post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output, preferably in a [Stacksnippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)

Answer (score 1):

Like this?

```js
var removeLocaleLink = $(".int-tooltip a, a.int-tooltip");
removeLocaleLink.each(function() {
  let href = $(this).attr("href")
  href = href.replace(/\/zh-hant\/|\/de\/|\/fr\/|\/es\/|\/pt-br\/|\/ja\/|\/ko\//, "/");
  $(this).attr("href",href);
  console.log(this.href)
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class="int-tooltip" href="/zh-hant/">/zh-hant</a>
<span class="int-tooltip"><a href="/zh-hant/">/zh-hant</a></span>
```